# jqGrid change selected row style ui-jqgrid ui-state-highlight for one grid only, not all the others on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqgrid

Our company uses hundreds of jqGrids.  I am adding one to a page that already has jqGrids on that page.  I may not alter the style or behavior for those grids.  The new grid that I am adding (also a jqGrid) must have a unique selected row style (background white and borders rbg(153, 153, 153)).

If I change the jqGrid style on the page this works on the new grid, but changes the other grids.  This is not allowed:
        /*This over-rides the normal jqGrid selected row style for the xyz grid*/
        .ui-jqgrid .ui-state-highlight { background: white; border-color: rgb(153, 153, 153); }

I have attempted to change the style when declaring the grid like this, but it didn't work:

```
    ResultsGrid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: data,
        minheight: 20,
        width: 700,
        height: '100%',
        //altRows: true,
        //altClass: 'myAltRowClass',
        colNames: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'aaa', hidden: true, key: true },
            { name: 'bbb', formatter: thingy.format_bbb },
            { name: 'ccc', hidden: true },
            { name: 'ddd', formatter: thingy.format_ddd, width: 80, align: 'center' },
            { name: 'eee', formatter: thingy.format_eee },
            { name: 'fff', hidden: true },
            { name: 'ggg', sortable: false, formatter: thingy.format_ggg, width: 25, align: 'center' }
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        emptyrecords: 'No Data',
        onSelectRow: function () {
            //ResultsGrid.removeClass('ui-jqgrid ui-state-highlight');
            //ResultsGrid.addClass('ui-jqgrid complaint_selectedrow');
            //.ui-jqgrid .ui-state-highlight { background: white; border-color: rgb(153, 153, 153); }

            //$("#table").removeClass('ui-jqgrid ui-state-highlight').addClass('ui-jqgrid complaint_selectedrow');

            //$("#table").removeClass(' ui-state-highlight').addClass('complaint_selectedrow');

            //$("head").append('<style type="text/css"></style>');
            //var new_stylesheet = $("head").children(':last');
            //new_stylesheet.html('.ui-jqgrid ui-state-highlight{background: white; border-color: rgb(153, 153, 153);}');

        alert('This alert does pop-up when a row is selected.');
        }
```

Please help if you have any ideas.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

oh my gosh I fixed it, the right way by using javascript in the onSelectRow function, like this:

```
    onSelectRow: function () {
        var sheet = document.createElement('style');
        sheet.innerHTML = ".ui-jqgrid .ui-state-highlight { background: white; border-color: rgb(153, 153, 153); }";
        document.body.appendChild(sheet);
    }
```

That did the trick!